# Make bashscript shorter with pipes

Tags: linux, bash, file, pipe, uniq

I have some textfiles (all files have this scheme in each line `123:abc`) and want to make two seperate files with these. One big file with all lines (but uniq) and with this a file with the strings after the token ":".

This here works:

```
cat *.txt >> bigtextfile.txt 
sort -u bigtextfile.txt -o bigtextfile.txt 
cat bigtextfile.txt | cut -d: -f2 >> bigtextfile-filtered.txt
```

But can i do this much shorter with pipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort` accepts multiple file inputs, so you can produce your `bigtextfile.txt` in one sitting :

```
sort -u *.txt -o bigtextfile.txt
```

`cut` also accepts a file input parameter, no need for `cat` :

```
cut -d: -f2 bigtextfile.txt >> bigtextfile-filtered.txt
```

If you don't need the `bigtextfile.txt` in itself and just use it as an intermediate to producing `bigtextfile-filtered.txt` you can do that in one line :

```
sort -u *.txt | cut -d: -f2 >> bigtextfile-filtered.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

```
sort -u *.txt | cut -d: -f2 >> bigtextfile-filtered.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat *.txt | sort -u | cut -d: -f2 >> bigtextfile-filtered.txt
```